# Jquery Uncheck the users last selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a Multi Select Box which contains the services and duration. If user selects some services then its duration is captured, if duration is exceed the limit then a alert is generated.How can i uncheck the last checked value by user so that duration is not reset if exceed limit.here is my code:

```
jQuery('.check-service').click(function () {

    serviceselected = jQuery("input.check-service:checked").length;
    serviceduration = 0;

    jQuery('input.check-service:checked').each(function () {

        serviceduration = parseInt(jQuery(this).val()) + parseInt(serviceduration);
        if (selectvalues == '') {
            selectvalues = jQuery(this).attr('title');
            serviceids = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        } else {
            selectvalues = selectvalues + "," + jQuery(this).attr('title');
            serviceids = serviceids + ", " + jQuery(this).attr('id');
        }

    });

    if (serviceduration >= '600') {
        alert("Selected Service is more than available time slot.");
        jQuery('input.check-service').attr('checked', false);
        console.log();


    }
```

Currently its unchecked all the checked valued.I just want to uncheck the last previous selected value.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
jQuery('#CheckboxID').click(function(){     //instead of class use id
    serviceselected = jQuery("input.check-service:checked").length;
    serviceduration = 0;
    jQuery('input.check-service:checked').each(function () {
        serviceduration = parseInt(jQuery(this).val()) + parseInt(serviceduration);
        if(selectvalues == '') {
            selectvalues = jQuery(this).attr('title');
            serviceids = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        } 
        else {
            selectvalues = selectvalues + "," + jQuery(this).attr('title');          
            serviceids = serviceids + ", " + jQuery(this).attr('id');
        }

    });
    if (serviceduration >= '600') {
        alert("Selected Service is more than available time slot.");
        jQuery(this).attr( 'checked', false );
        console.log();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant store last selected checkbox in some global variable.

```
var $lastChecked;

$(".check-service").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
        lastChecked = $(this);
    }
    //your logic
    //...
    //now when you have to uncheck:
    $lastChecked.removeAttr("checked");
})
```

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion...This is also working as above but i choose not to save in variable.So i selected the above answer.
one more thing. How can i remove Css style of this unchecked attributes.

Comment: Sudhanshu for remove Css add one more line under jQuery(this).attr( 'checked', false ); jQuery(this).removeClass('classname');